# User controls are not visible at runtime in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I created a user control `.ascx` and added it in master page by dragging and drop so that registering and everything is done by automatically.i can see that usercontrol contains Menu in design time ,but when i run it i am not seeing it in UI. Strange i checked page inspector console tab ,but no error throwing  only thing it showing is local site you have added it in compatibility view and `HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. The shortest valid doctype is “<!DOCTYPE html>”`.I am doing HTML 5 conversion also for this website which was in previous version ,but not complete.Can anybody tell me why this behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately i commented out the code for populating Menu, and Enableviewstate false, both corrected and working now